# Laravel validate url name and protocol

Tags: php, laravel

I need validate url. I need allow only main url sites, example:

```
http://example.com
https://example.com
```

I need prevent these urls on my site:

```
http://example.com/page/blahblahblah
https://example.com/other/bloa
```

I use regex:

```
'url' => ['required', 'url', 'regex:/((http:|https:)\/\/)[^\/]+/']
```

When user insert url, he can insert `http://example.com/page/blahblahblah` why? My regex is not working.. Validation is passing

Comment: You should consider doing this on the web-server level instead. did you try to use it with subdomain routing [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing) this might be a good direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following pattern to ensure a URL does not contain subdirectories:

```
^(?:\S+:\/\/)?[^\/]+\/?$
```

Explanation:

> ^ asserts position at start of the string
>
> Non-capturing group (?:\S+://)?
>
> ? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>
> \S+ matches any non-whitespace character (equal to [^\r\n\t\f\v ])
>
> + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>
> : matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
>
> / matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
>
> / matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
>
> Match a single character not present in the list below [^/]+
>
> + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>
> / matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
>
> /? matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
>
> ? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>
> $ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom validator and use a combination of filter_var and parse_url?

Something as follows will do the job...

```
<?php

$url = "http://example.com/page/blahblahblah";

if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    return false;
}

$parts = parse_url($url);

echo "{$parts['scheme']}://{$parts['host']}";
```